# PowerShell Parallels Jobs Speed improvements

Tags: powershell, powershell-7.0

So i Finaly  got my script working. YEYY!!!  Thanks to every one that helped out with this.. but  now  i have some questions i hope
you can provide some answers

**Question one**

Is `Get-ADComputer`  inside my `ForEach-Object` loop, is that  creating a new connection  to Active directory Every time
it iterates?   i notice  if you run command  as stand alone  i takes a few  secods  to connect to AD and  get  data.
is there  a better way  (reduce  conection overhead)?

```
$Do = $Clients | ForEach-Object -Parallel {
        $O = get-ADComputer -Identity $_ -Properties Enabled
```

**Question Two**
Is  this also  afecting the like previous  question ?

```
if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $_ -Count 2 -Quiet){  
    $ob = Get-HotFix -ComputerName $_ -Description 'Security Update'  | Select-Object -Last 1;
```

So even if i run in parallel  i noticed it takes over  50 min to retrive  data  from  200 PC's   is this normal?

**Output Data**

```
"Name","Description","KbPatch","Installed"
"PC-l146","PC Is Not Online","0","0"
"PC-l230","PC Is Not In AD or has been DISABLED","0","0"
"PC-l148","PC Is Not In AD or has been DISABLED","0","0"
"PC-l281","PC Is Not In AD or has been DISABLED","0","0"
"PC-L158","Security Update","KB4586786","11/25/2020 12:00:00 AM"
"PC-G028","Security Update","KB4570333","9/23/2020 12:00:00 AM"
"PC-l072","PC Is Not Online","0","0"
"PC-L279","Security Update","KB4577668","10/29/2020 12:00:00 AM"
"PC-l021","PC Is Not Online","0","0"
"PC-l035","PC Is Not In AD or has been DISABLED","0","0"
"PC-g005","PC Is Not In AD or has been DISABLED","0","0"
"PC-L068","Security Update","KB4580325","10/22/2020 12:00:00 AM"
```

**My Script final form**

```
Function Get-FileName{
    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName(“System.windows.forms”) | Out-Null
    $OpenFileDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
    $OpenFileDialog.initialDirectory = Get-Location
    $OpenFileDialog.filter = “All files (*.*)| *.*”
    $OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
    $OpenFileDialog.filename
}

$Importfile = Get-FileName
$Clients = Get-Content $Importfile

$Do = $Clients | ForEach-Object -Parallel {
    $O = get-ADComputer -Identity $_ -Properties Enabled
    try {
        if ($O."Enabled" -eq 'TRUE') {
            #CHECK IF PC IS  NETWORK ACCESSIBLE 
            try{ 
                if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $_ -Count 2 -Quiet){  
                    $ob = Get-HotFix -ComputerName $_ -Description 'Security Update'  | Select-Object -Last 1;
                    #GET  LATEST KB PATCH INSTALLED\
                    [pscustomobject]@{
                        #"CSName","Description","HotFixID","InstalledBy","InstalledOn"
                        Name =$ob.CSName ;
                        Description = $ob.Description;
                        KbPatch = $ob.HotFixID;
                        Installed = $ob.InstalledOn;
                    }
                }
                else{
                    throw "$_,PC Is Not Online";
                }
            }
            catch { 
                $Err = $_.Exception.Message.split(',')
                [pscustomobject]@{Name =$Err[0]; Description = $Err[1]; KbPatch =0; Installed =0}
            } 
        }
        else {
            throw "$_,PC Is Not In AD or has been DISABLED"; 
        }
    }
    catch {
        $Err = $_.Exception.Message.split(',')
        [pscustomobject]@{Name =$Err[0]; Description = $Err[1]; KbPatch =0; Installed =0}
    }
}
$Do | Export-Csv -path ./OutputFile.csv -Delimiter ';' -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: A new question has a come up   how can i catch  this exception  `"The RPC server is unavailable. (0x800706BA)";;"0";"0"`?

Comment: Unless I expect objects to change I always do a Get-ADComputer outside of a loop filtered in a way to get all the objects that I will need. Often just -Filter *. If I expect to be looking up a lot of times I will then convert this to a hash with the machine name (or other unique identifier) as the key and the matching AD object as the value. This speeds things immensely over calling Get-ADComputer repeatedly. As for how to catch RPC server unavailable errors, the answer is in your question. Use a Try-Catch construct.

Comment: You're stalling the pipeline by assigning the results to a variable (`$Do`), meaning that the script will not export the results until all parallel threads are completed (which also causes a high memory usage). Instead, directly pipe each item to the CSV file: `... } | Export-Csv -path ...`